# Hard drives not found in ubuntu Server installation (Suspected raid controller)

Tags: server, hard-drive, raid

So I have two servers, an IBM x336 & IBM x306M. Both are quite old and I am only using them for game hosting. I tried installing Ubuntu server on both machines and found that neither were detecting their hard drives. all hard drives are the manufacturers HDDs. So i came to the conclusion that ubuntu doesn't support either raid controller. Is there a way i can get ubuntu to detect them?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Boot a live image, run lspci -v and note down the controller (or paste it to a pastebin somewhere). Then you can google the controller in question to check for support.